# Exchange 421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to ConnectionReset

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010

I have exchange server 2010 with following detail:

Exchange Server 2010
Microsoft Corporation
Version: 14.03.0146.000

When I try to send a test email to yahoo without an attachment its delivered successfully, but when I add an attachment to this email is stays in the Exchange server queue for a long time, sometimes this email delivers to yahoo after 6 to 1 day, and sometimes not.

This is error code in exchange server:

```
Identity: PHOENIX-EX1\716\2651
Subject: test with attachement
Internet Message ID: <658A6724E2802248B6EB4DC9E775D8556DEA108E@PHOENIX-EX1.phoenixpower.co.om>
From Address: isehaq@phoenixom.co.om
Status: Ready
Size (KB): 1702
Message Source Name: FromLocal
Source IP: 255.255.255.255
SCL: -1
Date Received: 9/6/2013 10:04:56 PM
Expiration Time: 9/8/2013 10:04:56 PM
Last Error: 421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to ConnectionReset
Queue ID: PHOENIX-EX1\716
Recipients:  e42squ2010@yahoo.com;2;2;421 4.4.2 Connection dropped due to ConnectionReset;0;CN=internet,CN=Connections,CN=Exchange Routing Group (DWBGZMFD01QNBJR),CN=Routing Groups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=phoenixpower,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=phoenixpower,DC=co,DC=om
```

I can send same email to Gmail , hotmail account without issue.

sending log

```
2013-09-06T21:08:30.943Z,internet,08D079499566A968,14,192.168.111.40:63440,98.136.216.25:25,-,,Remote
2013-09-06T21:08:30.943Z,internet,08D079499566A969,0,,98.136.217.202:25,*,,attempting to connect
2013-09-06T21:08:31.068Z,internet,08D079499566A969,1,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,+,,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.144Z,internet,08D079499566A969,2,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,220 mta1364.mail.gq1.yahoo.com ESMTP YSmtpProxy service ready,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.144Z,internet,08D079499566A969,3,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,>,EHLO mail.phoenixpower.co.om,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.565Z,internet,08D079499566A969,4,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,250-mta1364.mail.gq1.yahoo.com,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.565Z,internet,08D079499566A969,5,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,250-8BITMIME,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.565Z,internet,08D079499566A969,6,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,250 SIZE 41943040,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.565Z,internet,08D079499566A969,7,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,*,2663,sending message
2013-09-06T21:08:32.565Z,internet,08D079499566A969,8,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,>,MAIL FROM:<isehaq@phoenixom.co.om> SIZE=1743480,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.987Z,internet,08D079499566A969,9,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,250 sender <isehaq@phoenixom.co.om> ok,
2013-09-06T21:08:32.987Z,internet,08D079499566A969,10,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,>,RCPT TO:<e42squ2010@yahoo.com>,
2013-09-06T21:08:33.423Z,internet,08D079499566A969,11,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,250 recipient <e42squ2010@yahoo.com> ok,
2013-09-06T21:08:33.439Z,internet,08D079499566A969,12,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,>,DATA,
2013-09-06T21:08:33.611Z,internet,08D079499566A969,13,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,<,354 end data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>,
2013-09-06T21:08:38.431Z,internet,08D079499566A969,14,192.168.111.40:63441,98.136.217.202:25,-,,Remote
2013-09-06T21:08:38.431Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,0,,98.138.112.32:25,*,,attempting to connect
2013-09-06T21:08:38.525Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,1,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,+,,
2013-09-06T21:08:39.414Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,2,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,220 mta1590.mail.ne1.yahoo.com ESMTP YSmtpProxy service ready,
2013-09-06T21:08:39.414Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,3,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,>,EHLO mail.phoenixpower.co.om,
2013-09-06T21:08:39.819Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,4,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,250-mta1590.mail.ne1.yahoo.com,
2013-09-06T21:08:39.819Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,5,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,250-8BITMIME,
2013-09-06T21:08:39.819Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,6,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,250 SIZE 41943040,
2013-09-06T21:08:39.819Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,7,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,*,2663,sending message
2013-09-06T21:08:39.819Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,8,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,>,MAIL FROM:<isehaq@phoenixom.co.om> SIZE=1743480,
2013-09-06T21:08:40.209Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,9,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,250 sender <isehaq@phoenixom.co.om> ok,
2013-09-06T21:08:40.209Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,10,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,>,RCPT TO:<e42squ2010@yahoo.com>,
2013-09-06T21:08:40.615Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,11,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,250 recipient <e42squ2010@yahoo.com> ok,
2013-09-06T21:08:40.631Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,12,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,>,DATA,
2013-09-06T21:08:40.740Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,13,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,<,354 end data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>,
2013-09-06T21:08:44.936Z,internet,08D079499566A96B,0,,62.231.248.5:25,*,,attempting to connect
2013-09-06T21:08:45.092Z,internet,08D079499566A96B,1,192.168.111.40:63446,62.231.248.5:25,+,,
2013-09-06T21:08:45.810Z,internet,08D079499566A96A,14,192.168.111.40:63442,98.138.112.32:25,-,,Remote
2013-09-06T21:08:45.810Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,0,,98.138.112.34:25,*,,attempting to connect
2013-09-06T21:08:45.919Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,1,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,+,,
2013-09-06T21:08:46.933Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,2,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,<,220 mta1257.mail.ne1.yahoo.com ESMTP YSmtpProxy service ready,
2013-09-06T21:08:46.933Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,3,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,>,EHLO mail.phoenixpower.co.om,
2013-09-06T21:08:47.323Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,4,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,<,250-mta1257.mail.ne1.yahoo.com,
2013-09-06T21:08:47.323Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,5,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,<,250-8BITMIME,
2013-09-06T21:08:47.323Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,6,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,<,250 SIZE 41943040,
2013-09-06T21:08:47.323Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,7,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,>,QUIT,
2013-09-06T21:08:47.698Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,8,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,<,221 mta1257.mail.ne1.yahoo.com,
2013-09-06T21:08:47.698Z,internet,08D079499566A96C,9,192.168.111.40:63449,98.138.112.34:25,-,,Local
2013-09-06T21:11:55.194Z,internet,08D079499566A96B,2,192.168.111.40:63446,62.231.248.5:25,-,,Remote
2013-09-06T21:11:55.194Z,internet,08D079499566A96D,0,,62.231.248.2:25,*,,attempting to connect
2013-09-06T21:11:55.210Z,internet,08D079499566A96D,1,192.168.111.40:10800,62.231.248.2:25,+,,
2013-09-06T21:15:05.249Z,internet,08D079499566A96D,2,192.168.111.40:10800,62.231.248.2:25,-,,Remote
```

Comment: enable full SMTP logging in Exchange and post the pertinent part of the SMTP log for a message being sent.

Comment: i already add SMTP log in my question.

Comment: and it hangs right there?  No DATA is ever sent?  Is there any kind of DUL (like Trend Micro, TrustedSource, etc.) or anti-spam in use?

Comment: i was using Microsoft essential security, i uninstalled it because exchange server stop because of it

Answer (score 1):

Some suggest this may be caused by a faulty Send Connector. Creating a new connector may resolve the issue in some cases.

http://www.networkadminsecrets.com/2010/04/421-and-451-exchange-2007-errors.html gives us the Powershell script to do this:

```
New-SendConnector -Name ForceHelo -AddressSpaces problemdomain.com -ForceHELO $true
```

Another solution, suggested for Exchange 2007, but possibly worth trying in 2010, is disable autotuning on your network interface.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951291/en-us gives the commands (to be run from an administrative command prompt):

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
```